# Where to find modern Romantic style piano composers?

Tags: composers, romantic-period, modern-music

I've been enjoying Chopin, Mendelssohn, Liszt, Rach and other composers in the Romantic style, specifically piano solos and occasionally trios. I particularly like Chopin's Ballades, Nocturnes and Barcarolle, as well as Mendelssohn's piano trios.

I've also found some modern composers who compose in that style, but always buried deep in the back alley of the Internet. I found [this guy](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCI_okr26VPUlPe3NcvWYcnA) 2 years ago. These are my favourites by him:

Recently, I fell in love with [another composer](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYk8_UUyPTbO-KuKXtMao1A) on Youtube. His Sonata in E minor is astounding, reminds me of Chopin's sonatas with a bit of Liszt influence as well:

Since it's a bit long, my favourite section begins at 17:39, but the entire third movement is beautiful.

There are some amazing hidden gems buried deep in Youtube.

When I Google search "romantic music" it comes up with those composers that lived 200 years ago. When I search "modern romantic music" it comes up with some love songs. "modern classical music" yields some compositions that sound like Mozart (I'm not a big fan of Mozart) and "modern classical romantic music" also returns those love songs. "chopin like music" gives me Scriabin and Balakirev, so I'm guessing searching in this way won't give me anything new.

I've been searching for more like this, any pointers on where to find them?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be migrated to Music Fans.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for the heads up. I mainly use Stack Overflow for code related questions so I'm a bit new to the other sites.